# Is there a way to check which process is recieving User input?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, process

Is there a way to check which process is receiving user input from a complete list of all running processes? For example:

```
  PROCESSENTRY32 procentry;
HANDLE hproc;
BOOL retval, ProcFound = false;

hproc = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0); //GetsSnapshotOfAllProcesses
if(hproc == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{ // If Couldnt get snapshot 
   MessageBox(NULL, "Unable To Get Snapshot", "LoaderError", MB_OK);
   return false;
}
procentry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); // Initialize
retval = Process32First(hproc, &procentry); //Copies Snapshot procentry

while(retval)
{
    **if(UserInput == TRUE))**
    {
    return procentry.th32ProcessID; //
    }
    retval = Process32Next(hproc, &procentry); // 
}
return 0;
```

}

Is there a function that will let me check which process  is receiving user input?

```
if(UserInput == TRUE))
```

Also, is there a way to translate the processes to a string?

Comment: `GetForegroundWindow` will tell you which window the user is currently working with. You should be able to get the process from that returned window handle.

Comment: Get the top window and check if it has a dialog box in focus ?
Then, if true, get the process associated with that window handle ?

Comment: If possible I would like to get the Window from the process as opposed to getting that process from the window.

Comment: You will need to go via the Window (GetWindowThreadProcessId)

Comment: @AlexK: A non-dialog can have the input focus.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a function that will return the process that contains the window that currently has the input focus. You have to get the window and determine the process from that. Why does it matter to you whether you get the window from the process or the process from the window?

Answer (score 2):

`GetForegroundWindow()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` is the way to go:

```
DWORD dwProcessID = 0;
HWND hFGWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
if (hFGWnd != NULL)
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hFGWnd, &dwProcessID);
return dwProcessID;
```